# How to expand active file tab names in SQL Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Is there anyway I can expand the names of any query tabs I have open in SQL Server Management Studio?  It's almost impossible to navigate them properly if I have more than five open.

Comment: I've tried switching to windows instead of tabs for this reason, but it didn't help. Hope someone comes up with an answer.

Answer (score 19):

You can shorten the display in each tab under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Editor Tab and Status Bar.

I would suggest turning off "Include Login Name" and "Include server name" for starters, see if that helps.

**Setting these:**

[image: SSMS Options Window]

**Shortens the tab from:**

[image: SSMS Tabs before]

**to:**

[image: SSMS Tabs after]

Comment: This is a great tip and works on my machine.  I wish it was also available in SSMS 2005 as well...

Comment: It's just a shame you can't do the same for table views. Or can you?

Comment: Can you fix your images? I would greatly appreciate if you could replace the image in the question, too.

Comment: Looks like ImageShack turfed all the freeloaders.   My account has been wiped... I'll see if I can dig up the images again and rehost them somewhere.

Comment: Okay, fixed.  Awesome that SO has image hosting now!